# Running tensorflow application using django with wsgi

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, tensorflow, wsgi

I deployed my application which runs with Tesorflow object detection API on Ubuntu 16.04LTS. It is a web application running on django and i want to serve it with apache and wsgi. When i access the apache server through my server's IP address i get the following error:

```
ImportError at /

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: PyBytes_AsStringAndSize


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Comment: Explain the setup a little more. What systems, host information?

Comment: Please tell your python version (I assume Python >3.5?) and `tensorflow` version. Issue `pip list | grep tensorflow` and add the output to your question.

Comment: What version of Python is mod_wsgi actually compiled for? This looks like it may not be using Python 3.5. It has to be compiled for the specific version of Python you want to use. You cannot point a mod_wsgi compiled for one Python version at the files of another Python version of virtual environment. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-shared-library and http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use